# Parse nested JSON response from LinkedIn

Tags: android, json, linkedin-api

I have been trying different things all day, but I still can't parse this JSON response. I successfully got a response from LinkedIn (I know, because I logged it), and now I'm trying to extract values from it, but the code I am using is creating an error saying there is no value of `firstName`. My 2nd log statement won't print. My 1st log statement, the response, is printed below at the bottom. What am I doing wrong?

**My class where I call the API**

```
package org.azurespot.awesomesde;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.linkedin.platform.APIHelper;
import com.linkedin.platform.errors.LIApiError;
import com.linkedin.platform.listeners.ApiListener;
import com.linkedin.platform.listeners.ApiResponse;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class LinkedInLoggedInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String urlLinkedIn = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name)?format=json";
    JSONObject results;
    TextView firstName;
    TextView lastName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_linked_in_logged_in);

        firstName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewFirst);
        lastName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewLast);

        APIHelper apiHelper = APIHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        apiHelper.getRequest(this, urlLinkedIn, new ApiListener() {
            @Override
            public void onApiSuccess(ApiResponse apiResponse) {
                // Success!
                Log.i("LINKEDIN RESPONSE: ", apiResponse.toString()); // 1st log

                try {
                    results = new JSONObject(apiResponse.toString());

                    Log.i("NAME FROM LINKED IN: ", results.get("firstName").toString()); // 2nd log

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onApiError(LIApiError liApiError) {
                // Error making GET request!
                liApiError.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    // get first name
    public void linkedInFirst(View v){
        try {
            firstName.setText(results.get("firstName").toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // get last name
    public void linkedInLast(View v) {

    }
}
```

**Error from Logcat**

```
05-08 18:58:38.227 18345-18345/org.azurespot.awesomesde W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for firstName
05-08 18:58:38.227 18345-18345/org.azurespot.awesomesde W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
05-08 18:58:38.227 18345-18345/org.azurespot.awesomesde W/System.err:     at org.azurespot.awesomesde.LinkedInLoggedInActivity$1.onApiSuccess(LinkedInLoggedInActivity.java:42)
05-08 18:58:38.227 18345-18345/org.azurespot.awesomesde W/System.err:     at com.linkedin.platform.APIHelper$1.onResponse(APIHelper.java:99)
05-08 18:58:38.227 18345-18345/org.azurespot.awesomesde W/System.err:     at com.linkedin.platform.APIHelper$1.onResponse(APIHelper.java:95)
05-08 18:58:38.227 18345-18345/org.azurespot.awesomesde W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
05-08 18:58:38.227 18345-18345/org.azurespot.awesomesde W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
05-08 18:58:38.227 18345-18345/org.azurespot.awesomesde W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
05-08 18:58:38.227 18345-18345/org.azurespot.awesomesde W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-08 18:58:38.227 18345-18345/org.azurespot.awesomesde W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
05-08 18:58:38.227 18345-18345/org.azurespot.awesomesde W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
05-08 18:58:38.227 18345-18345/org.azurespot.awesomesde W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-08 18:58:38.227 18345-18345/org.azurespot.awesomesde W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-08 18:58:38.227 18345-18345/org.azurespot.awesomesde W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
05-08 18:58:38.227 18345-18345/org.azurespot.awesomesde W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

**One of my log statements, the response**

```
05-08 18:38:45.577 7028-7028/org.azurespot.awesomesde I/LINKEDIN RESPONSE:: {"StatusCode":200,"responseData":"{\n  \"firstName\": \"AFirstName\",\n  \"id\": \"hZvMRB-3Yg\",\n  \"lastName\": \"ALastName\"\n}","Location":""}
```

Comment: Please check your JSON object closely. Is there a firstName key at the top level?

Comment: @cricket_007, sorry I'm quite new to using JSON... where do I find such a key? I only have the LinkedIn response that looks like a JSON response, but then it has that StatusCode... which throws me off a bit.

Comment: The response you get has 2 keys, a statusCode and responseData. You need to get the nested object of the responseData before you can access the firstName

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: Great thanks, I will look into this more.

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007, I was able to figure it out!

Comment: Welcome! Gson/Jackson are really useful libraries for doing some more complex JSON things within Java

Answer (score 0):

Great, thanks to @cricket_007, I was able to trace how to solve this. I have a nested JSON file as a response, which means I must get the first level first, which is the `responseData` key, and extract that into another new `JSONObject`, and then from there, I can extract the first and last name. Here's the working code snipets:

```
JSONObject results;
JSONObject resultsInner;
TextView firstName;
TextView lastName;

@Override
            public void onApiSuccess(ApiResponse apiResponse) {
                // Success!
                Log.i("LINKEDIN RESPONSE: ", apiResponse.toString());

                try {
                    results = new JSONObject(apiResponse.toString());
                    // must get the key responseData first, then will extract values from it
                    resultsInner = new JSONObject(results.getString("responseData"));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

...

```
// get first name
    public void linkedInFirst(View v){
        try {
            firstName.setText(resultsInner.getString("firstName"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // get last name
    public void linkedInLast(View v) {
        try {
            lastName.setText(resultsInner.getString("lastName"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```